# ASP.NET Web Forms - Seeder not working with MySQL connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to follow the ASP.NET Web Forms tutorial, just with a MySQL connection instead of local: [ASP.NET Web Forms - Create the Data Access Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer)

I already tested that the connection string works, because I made a dummy table in an existing DB and I can see it in the Server Explorer when  I run the app.

But according to the tutorial, it was also supposed to create a DB and tables and seed it. But nothing happens.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="myProject" connectionString="Data Source=MY_PC_NAME;User Id=testuser; Password=testpassword; Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This is the `ProjectContext` file:

```
namespace myProject.Models
{
    public class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectContext() : base("base_name")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `ProjectDatabaseInitializer`:

```
public class ProjectDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProjectContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ProjectContext context)
    {
        GetItems().ForEach(i => context.Items.Add(i));
        GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
    }
// some seeding lists below
```

I then added the initializer to the `Global.asax.cs`:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ProjectDatabaseInitializer());
```

And both `Items` and `Categories` have their corresponding `Item` and `Category` models.

But when I run the app, the Server Explorer remains empty.

Note that I modified the original code of the tutorial a bit

Comment: Exactly, the new company I'm moving into has legacy projects but the newer ones are with Core. I come from PHP so I also need to learn many things. I know Web Forms is very very outdated

Comment: In the constructor arguments to the DbContext, you're passing "base_name". But that's not what your connection string is named. Are you sure it's inserting data into the correct database you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `base("base_name")` in your ProjectContext has same **name** as in the Web.config "name" -> <add name="**base_name**" connectionString="....

Seed method will not be called until your **fist call for your context**.
Example: Add in your Default.aspx this

```
  private ProjectContext context = new ProjectContext ();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            var user = context.Items.ToList(); 
  }
```

This will trigger `Seed()` method in your `"ProjectDatabaseInitializer.cs"`.

If problem still persists, try to change "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelchanges" to "DropCreateDatabaseAlways". But before that, make sure, that you know differences between DropCreateDatabaseIfModelchanges and DropCreateDatabaseAlways.